# Python - While loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, range

I am trying to make a program that ask customers to enter number of items they would like to purchase.The program then finds the subtotal and the total price with tax. I am confused on how to add a while loop such that it keeps on asking the price of the items depending on how many items the user put, after which it will add all the items together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add what you have tried and where you are stuck. Here is a pseudo code to start with.

```
read the number of items as num
initialise total to zero
while num > 0:
    read the price of the each item as price
    calculate the tax and add it to price
    add the taxed price of each item to total
    decrement num
print sum
```